# What happens if two namespaces have the same variable name?

Tags: c++

Say you have two namespaces and both have a function with the same name. If you say your "using" both namespaces, when you call the function, which namespace's variable does it use?

For instance:

```
#include <library1>
#include <library2>

using namespace1;
using namespace2;

int main()
{
     myfunction(); //exists in both namespaces under the same name
}
```

Which namespace's function is called?

Comment: does it have the same signature?

Comment: @MarcoA. What's a signature?

Comment: :( A signature it's.. well.. arguments of the function

Comment: Wont compile, and will give ambiguous symbol error

Comment: @MarcoA. Oh I see. Yes, assume they have identical signatures.

Comment: This is exactly the issue namespaces are designed to avoid...

Comment: @MarcoA. Not return type.

Comment: @dfg Try it out. You would get (after fixing the code, and depending on your compiler) something like `error: call of overloaded ‘myfunction()’ is ambiguous`.

Comment: This sounds like something that you can easily test, yourself, in 5 minutes. Any reason you can't, and have to ask this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the functions have the same name and signature (arguments, not return types) during the lookup process (unqualified), it's ambiguous:

```
namespace A {   
 void fun() {
 }
}

namespace B {  
 void fun() {
 }
}

using namespace A;
using namespace B;

int main()
{
   fun(); // Ambiguous
}
```

<kbd>[See for yourself](http://ideone.com/jF0cUc)</kbd>

The compiler doesn't know which one should be used for the intended call (if you don't call any, it won't complain). Notice that this problem is exactly the issue that namespaces are designed to solve. You should never pollute the global namespace by indiscriminately `using namespace` stuff and, as a good rule of thumb, it's usually better to qualify the functions you're using (also for readability's sake).

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! I'll accept it as soon as I'm allowed to.

Comment: Worth mentioning that if you *don't* call the function, this is “perfectly fine”.  The C++ compiler will only fail compilation if it really has to because it cannot figure out what you've meant it to do.

Answer (score 3):

The name lookup of `myfunction` is then ambiguous and a C++ compiler will refuse to compile it.

e.g:

```
namespace namespace1 {
    void myfunction() {}
}

namespace namespace2 {
    void myfunction() {}
}

using namespace namespace1;
using namespace namespace2;

int main()
{
     myfunction();
}




$ g++ t.cpp 
t.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cpp:14:17: error: call of overloaded ‘myfunction()’ is ambiguous
      myfunction();
                 ^
t.cpp:14:17: note: candidates are:
t.cpp:6:10: note: void namespace2::myfunction()
     void myfunction() {}
          ^
t.cpp:2:10: note: void namespace1::myfunction()
     void myfunction() {}
          ^
```